# linux change date format in file with full year

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to change the date format in file with the full year.  This is my data.

```
06/30/21 07/01/21 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/21 07/07/21 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/21 07/19/21 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/21 07/22/21 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/21 07/26/21 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

This is what I would like the data to look like.

```
06/30/2021 07/01/2021 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/2021 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/2021 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/2021 07/22/2021 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/2021 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

Can't just do a massive replace like I want to because 21 is in various places in the file.

```
sed 's/21/2021/' junk_dates1
06/30/2021 07/01/21 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/21 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/21 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/2021/21 07/22/21 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/21 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

Do not know of a way to use the anchor trick because there is data after the dates.

```
sed 's/21$/2021/' junk_dates1
06/30/21 07/01/21 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/21 07/07/21 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/21 07/19/21 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/21 07/22/21 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/21 07/26/21 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

Comment: You can anchor to the beginning `^` and then use groups to reinsert or modify.

Comment: Consider whether anchoring to a slash and a space would suit your usecase: `sed 's-/21 -/2021 -`

Comment: you don't have any records for year other than 2021?

Comment: @αғsнιη in my bigger data sets I have other years. I do have a way to filter by year so I picked 2021 to try to make life simple. If you have a way to do more than one year that would be appreciated. I actually have 2015 to 2022.

Answer (score 3):

I propose this

```bsh
$ sed 's;\(../../\)21;\12021;g' foo.txt
06/30/2021 07/01/2021 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/2021 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/2021 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/2021 07/22/2021 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/2021 55457021206837001077531 ransom text
```

---

- `\(../../\)21` slash parenthesis `\(...\)` captures the pattern `char char slash char char slash`, which is referenced in the substitution by `\1`. After the pattern is `21`, which is replaced by `2021`.

With the option `-E` (`--regexp-extended`) is clearer: `$ sed 's;(../../)21;\12021;g'`.

Comment: can you help me understand this please? I know the `s` for substitute, `g` for global, `;` for the separator or delimiter. Not sure about this part `\(../../\)21;\1`.

Comment: @cokedude I've edited the answer, if you have any doubt just tell me.

Comment: I understand all but the `\1`.

Comment: @cokedude Something like this: `s;\(<capture pattern>\);<captured pattern>;` where `<captured pattern>` is referenced by the `\1`. In this case `\(../../\)` → `06/30/` (or any other), `\1` → `06/30/`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -E -e 's=^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) =\1/\2/20\3 \4/\5/20\6 =' input.txt 
06/30/2021 07/01/2021 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/2021 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/2021 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/2021 07/22/2021 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/2021 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

This will work for any 2-digit year that needs to be prefixed with `20`, including `21`.   It uses 6 capture groups to capture the day, month, and year numbers for the first and second space-separated fields.

BTW, note the space character after both of the `21`s in the regex.  **That's** the "anchor point" (or disambiguation point or identifying marker or whatever you want to call it) that you need - it's not just "21" you need to look for, it's "21 and a space".  Kind of.  That's not exactly what I ended up doing (a long match pattern with multiple capture groups anchored at the start of the line, `^`), but it was where I started thinking about how to match a 2 digit year that wasn't at the end of a line.

Note, however, that while this fixes one of your problems, it perpetuates the ambiguity problem inherent to MM/DD/YYYY and DD/MM/YYYY date formats.   Use dates based on ISO 8601, YYYY-MM-DD instead.  For example:

```
$ sed -E -e 's=^([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) ([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2}) =20\3-\1-\2 20\6-\4-\5 =' input.txt 
2021-06-30 2021-07-01 05436841182400056721972 random text
2021-07-06 2021-07-07 05436841188400057034635 random text
2021-07-17 2021-07-19 05410191199637000037473 random text
2021-07-21 2021-07-22 55483821203091001733933 random text
2021-07-24 2021-07-26 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

---

BTW, this would be a bit easier to read with perl regexes, using `\d\d` instead of `[0-9]{2}`:

```
$ perl -pe 's=^(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) (\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) =20$3-$1-$2 20$6-$4-$5 =' input.txt 
2021-06-30 2021-07-01 05436841182400056721972 random text
2021-07-06 2021-07-07 05436841188400057034635 random text
2021-07-17 2021-07-19 05410191199637000037473 random text
2021-07-21 2021-07-22 55483821203091001733933 random text
2021-07-24 2021-07-26 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

Unfortunately, not many versions of `sed` understand perl's `\d`.  The only one I know of is [super sed](http://sed.sf.net/grabbag/ssed/) which has a `-R` option to tell it to use perl regular expression syntax:

```
ssed -R 's=^(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) (\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d) =20\3-\1-\2 20\6-\4-\5 =' input.txt
```

If you're running on Debian, it's in the `ssed` package.  It may be packaged for other distros too.  Either way, there's not really any benefit over just using `perl -p` or `perl -n`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the character positions (15 and 6) where you want to insert `20` is always the same:

```
sed 's/.\{15\}/&20/;s/.\{6\}/&20/' file
06/30/2021 07/01/2021 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/2021 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/2021 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/2021 07/22/2021 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/2021 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's:/:/20:2; s:/:/20:4' < file
```

would insert `20` after the 2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> occurrences of `/` on each line.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's:/\(.. \):/20\1:g' file
06/30/2021 07/01/2021 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/2021 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/2021 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/2021 07/22/2021 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/2021 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

You should really consider changing your date format to YYYY/MM/DD or similar though as it's far easier to work with, e.g. you can sort and compare dates in that format as strings:

```
$ sed 's:\(.....\)/\(..\) :20\2/\1 :g' file
2021/06/30 2021/07/01 05436841182400056721972 random text
2021/07/06 2021/07/07 05436841188400057034635 random text
2021/07/17 2021/07/19 05410191199637000037473 random text
2021/07/21 2021/07/22 55483821203091001733933 random text
2021/07/24 2021/07/26 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

or ISO 8601 standard:

```
$ sed 's:\(..\)/\(..\)/\(..\):20\3-\1-\2:g' file
2021-06-30 2021-07-01 05436841182400056721972 random text
2021-07-06 2021-07-07 05436841188400057034635 random text
2021-07-17 2021-07-19 05410191199637000037473 random text
2021-07-21 2021-07-22 55483821203091001733933 random text
2021-07-24 2021-07-26 55457021206837001077531 random text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/21 /20&/g' filename

06/30/2021 07/01/2021 05436841182400056721972 random text
07/06/2021 07/07/2021 05436841188400057034635 random text
07/17/2021 07/19/2021 05410191199637000037473 random text
07/21/2021 07/22/2021 55483821203091001733933 random text
07/24/2021 07/26/2021 55457021206837001077531 random text
```